# cx_oracle jupyter notebook NLS_LANG error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cx-oracle

In the sqlplus script, I did this

```
unset NLS_LANG
```

How I can do the same thing for cx_oracle in jupyter notebook ?

I am following this example and got the error.

[How can I access Oracle from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521692/how-can-i-access-oracle-from-python)

```
DatabaseError: ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error before and I ran below codes to set the language by running an alter command.  Make sure you commit afterwards.

```
c.execute(u'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE=American')
```